Advise on my circuit that uses voltage regulators, a motor, a heating pad and some modules
I want to fix my broken filament heater for my 3d printer. The idea is to measure the temperature/humidity, use some logic on an esp-01S to decide of the heating element should go on or off. I have already build it, but it seams to be unstable and the circuit (display, esp-01s) stop working after 30 seconds. I have no clue where I go wrong.

is this the way?
what can be done better?
are there major flaws?

I used the following elements (most of them I already had and thought should be good enough):

24v power supply
voltage regulators (AMS1117 3.3v, 7805) (the screw is my radiator)
diodes (I used Zeners, because I have nothing else)
5v relais
NPN BC337 (should be similar to the 2N2222?)
DHT11 (temp sensor)
small display
esp-01s



CircuitLab Schematic 864s4452535p

Love the heatsink

That schematic is hard to see

Since your heater is a purely resistive load, instead of the (pretty awkwardly placed) relay, a simple "logic level" n-channel MOSFET would do (you need to put that on the ground side of your heater, and connect the other side permanently to 24V). That would save you your BJT transistor, and its dedicated 5 V supply; it would also save quite a bit of power, because in this circuit, aside from the heater, the relay coil is going to be the thing drawing most power. And that's why your 7805 gets hot. The self-shutdown might be the reason why your device turns off.
So, eliminating the relay gets rid of the 7805, your very nice heat sink, and generally most of the space used on your proto board. That's an improvement that I would certainly take!
Other than that, I'm a bit skeptical on your marking son your "ESP-01s" block: it seems your display is connected via I²C (SCL/SDA), and that's not "tx" and "rx", but a bidirectional bus. So make sure to actually connect the display to your microcontroller's I²C ports.
I'm also missing the weak pull up resistor on the data connection between the DHT11 and your microcontroller, but you might be using  microcontroller built-in pull up (which is fine!).
Bonus point for replacing the relay with a MOSFET: A relay can only be switched so many times before it breaks. Your MOSFET won't complain if you turn it off and on several times per second for hours on end. That way, you can control your heater power – using PWM. That allows you to build things like a PID controller, should you need to actually achieve a specific temperature.
However, I just realized your regulator for the digital side only is designed to deal up to maybe 12 V to 15V input; you might want to replace it with a switch mode supply module; there's many good ones, like these. Make sure they can output the current you need (for the microcontroller, display and sensor).

But if the 7805 is removed, AMS1117 will need an even more creative heat sink if it survives at all :)

@Jens oh, true, that's just an 1117, didn't notice that. Yep, this shouts "use a SMPS module".

@MarcusMüller, this is exactly the answer I was wishing for. I will redesign my logic with the MOSFET as you describe controlled by the PWM of the ESP8266. The ESP rx and tx can be used as GPIO1 and GPIO3 and set to scl and sda respectively, this works with esphome and needs no change (esp-s01 pinout), DHT11 indeed has an onboard pull-up. I indeed need to re-rethink my power supply for the esp.

@MarcusMüller To complete your answer, what would be a commonly used MOSFET to use in a circuit like this? (which one should I order?) IRLZ44N? AO3400? IRL540N? And what SMPS would you advise?

Two big problems:

The BC337 is configured as an emitter follower (common drain), and won't produce the full 5V across the relay coil. You'll always get 0.7V less than the ESP01 output, so 2.6V. Use a common source arrangement. Base resistor can probably be over 1kΩ.

The screw is not good enough for use as a heat-sink. It doesn't have enough surface area to dispose of heat to the environment faster than it is receiving it electrically. Assuming 200mA of current through the 7805, and 19V across it, power is \$0.2A\times 19V=3.8W\$. That's too much for a simple screw to deal with, and the 7805 will eventually go into thermal shutdown. Use a buck DC-DC converter for 5V, or a proper heat-sink.


